# Downloading an HTML page

Tags: downloading

Is there a way for me to download an HTML page to a folder on my smartphone?

I usually make a copy in PDF format but sometimes it does not get very good.

Comment: @Izzy I migrated the question to this site: [Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46207/downloading-an-html-page-on-android)

Comment: Please note that [crossposting is not welcome at SE sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/192154), even if they would fit on multiple of them. I've adjusted your post at SR accordingly, so the questions are now slightly different (asking for an app there, and for some app independent onboard solution here). Good hunting!